# Exporting NetCDF file in MODIS sinusoidal grid with xarray

Tags: python-3, xarray

I have 18 TIFF files in the MODIS sinusoidal grid I would like to convert to one file in NetCDF format.  I have converted the tifs to an xarray `xarray.core.dataset.Dataset` format called `stacked`.  At this point if my projection is WGS 84 I can usually export to NetCDF like so:

```
stacked.lat.attrs['long_name'] = 'latitude'
stacked.lat.attrs['units'] = 'degrees_north'
stacked.lat.attrs['standard_name'] = 'latitude'
   
stacked.long.attrs['long_name'] = 'longitude'
stacked.long.attrs['units'] = 'degrees_east'
stacked.long.attrs['standard_name'] = 'longitude'
   
    
stacked[variable].attrs['coordinates'] = 'time lat long'
```

but since MODIS is not in degrees this causes a problem.  I tried to change the units to `'meters'` but that did not work.  Is there a way to export to NetCDF with MODIS (https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/modis-sinusoidal-3/) instead of WGS 84?

Answer (score 0):

When I was processing MODIS data in to UTM in arcmap I found this website very useful.

https://code.env.duke.edu/projects/mget/wiki/SinusoidalMODIS

A key thing I picked up on was the transformation required which they suggest is Longitude_rotation.